# TLS (1.2) be enabled for JDBC connections

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, jdbc, tls1.2

We have a Java 1.8 based application which connects to SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL  databases using JDBC connection.

My requirement is to secure JDBC transactions by using TLS (1.2) be enabled for JDBC connections?

How can I achieve this without changing the connection string. My intention is to do this without disturbing the existing connection string.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Java 1.8. ........

Comment: Is your problem specifically with enabling TLS 1.2, or just with using TLS/SSL? I don't think that can be done without manipulating connection strings (if the driver doesn't already default to using TLS).

Comment: Actually both. Also does the driver by default use TLS?

Comment: Depends on the driver

Comment: You can use 12.2 JDBC driver ojdbc8.jar and you need JCE unlimited policy files. Check out more details on this blog (https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2c-tlsv12%2c-jks-or-oracle-wallets)